# PHP Turn a multidimensional array into nested list

Tags: php, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

I get results from a MYSQL query, and I'm struggling turning this array into a nested list :

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Esprit
        [post_id] => 240
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => GC
        [post_id] => 241
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Guess
        [post_id] => 242
        [folder_id] => 236
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [post_title] => Jewels
                        [post_id] => 250
                        [folder_id] => 242
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [post_title] => Products-shots
                                        [post_id] => 251
                                        [folder_id] => 250
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [post_title] => New-Collection
                                                        [post_id] => 252
                                                        [folder_id] => 251
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Guess-Connect
        [post_id] => 243
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Nautica
        [post_id] => 244
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Obaku
        [post_id] => 245
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Police
        [post_id] => 246
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Roamer
        [post_id] => 247
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Superdry
        [post_id] => 248
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Vulcain
        [post_id] => 249
        [folder_id] => 236
    )

)
```

I tried tons of codes, but none can get me this precise output :

```
<ul>
    <li>Esprit</li>
    <li>GC</li>
    <li>Guess
        <ul>
            <li>Jewels</li>
            <li>Products-shot</li>
            <li>New-collection</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Guess-Connect</li>
    <li>Nautica</li>
    <li>Obaku</li>
    <li>Police</li>
    <li>Roamer</li>
    <li>Superdry</li>
    <li>Vulcain</li>
</ul>
```

I'd really appreciate help ! Thanks in advance

Comment: The SQL result structure is wrong. You have nested children, but you want to consider them as childrens of same parent. What is wrong? Your concept, or the database structure?

Comment: Actually I get unnested data from phpMyAdmin. I use a function to build up a new array nesting the children to their parents according to a 'parent_id' column.

Answer (score 2):

You can only put second level display try this:

```
function second_level_list( $arr ){
  foreach( $arr as $item ){
     echo '<li>';
     echo $item['post_title'];
     echo '</li>';
     if( isset($item['children']) && is_array($item['children']) ){
       second_level_list( $item['children']);
     }
  }
}

<ul>
   <?php  foreach( $array as $list  ): ?> 
     <li><?php echo $list['post_title'] ?>
     <?php if( isset( $list['children'] ) && is_array($list['children']) ): ?>
       <ul> 
          <?php second_level_list( $list['children'] ); ?>
       </ul> 
      <?php endif; ?>  
     </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>  
</ul>
```

Complete results https://3v4l.org/YD0Yc

Answer (score 1):

try the following solution:

```
function htmlList($arr)
{
    $list = '<ul>';
    foreach ($arr as $value)
    {
        $listItem = (is_array($value) ? htmlList($value) : $value);
        $list .= "<li>$listItem</li>";
    }
    $list .= '</ul>';
    return $list;
}
echo htmlList($array);
```

Comment: Where is ’make_list` defined?

Comment: I think answerer means `htmlList()`. You need to call the same function for the sublists.

Comment: `htmlList($array)` instead of `htmlList($arr)`

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your PHP code a little bit, and seems to work for me :

```
function second_level_list( $arr ){
  foreach( $arr as $item ){
     echo '<li>'.$item['post_title'].'</li>';
     if( isset($item['children']) && is_array($item['children']) ){
     echo '<ul>';
       second_level_list( $item['children']);
     echo '</ul>';
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks mate